# Why my token isn't deleted?

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I have user log in and sign in. I make that when user signs in, his token is rememberede and when he again click on app he don't have to go to LogIn activity. But, the problem is when I logOut him, he goes to the LogIn activity but when he exit from LogIn activity and when he again clicks on app, he goes directly to the Main Activity, so his token is not deleted. How to fix that?
Here is my LogIn activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    credentials = new Credentials();
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            username = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

            String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (getUsername.length()>0 && getPassword.length()>0 ) {
                credentials.setUsername(getUsername);
                credentials.setPassword(getPassword);

                allOperations();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_fields , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my Main activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SharedPreferences shf = getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final  String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);

        if(strPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        initializeInjector();
        initialize();}
```

Here is my logic for LogOut button(It is on fragment on Main activity):

```
 buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
```

And my manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".view.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".view.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: didi yo check what you are getting from SharedPreferences

Comment: No..what should I write?

Comment: just Create a Tost with the string "strPref"

Comment: I have logged strPref and it is the same token like when user exit from app and again comes..so token is not deleted...

Comment: what your getting from it ?

Comment: I am getting the same token like token when user launch app...

Comment: Call commit() in place of apply().

Comment: after the log out when you came back are you getting same?

Comment: I have done it but does it is the same like apply...

Comment: I am getting the same user's token like he is logged in

Comment: To remove them all SharedPreferences.Editor.clear() followed by a commit()

Comment: With this I will remove all from shared preferences but I want to delete just this token

Answer (score 1):

Change your buttonOk onclick Listener line from

```
sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").apply();
```

to

```
sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").commit();
```

Comment: remove `getActivity().finish();` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your SharedPreferences  names are different one is "Token pref" and other is "Token prefs"

Comment: I fix the names but the problem is the same again...I really don't know what to do anymore..:(

Comment: Make your SharedPreferences names are identical and try sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").commit(); in the logout section

Comment: didi you got the answer